# Controller retornando partial view em uma modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um botão em minha tela que realizada chamada a um método no meu controlador (Ajax) que retorna uma *partialView* por padrão.

```
$("#btn-Visualizar-Rotina").click(function() {
            var codUnimetPcp = '@Model.UnidadeMetalica.COD_UNIMET_PCP';
            $("#modal-Rotina").load("Rotina/Index", { "codUnimetPCP": codUnimetPcp }, function (result) {
                $("#modal-Rotina").modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
            });
        });
```

Porém, no meu controle, preciso validar novamente se o usuário realmente possui permissão no método em questão, e em caso negativo derivar para uma página padrão de segurança. Na função de validação, quando o usuário não possui acesso, tenho o seguinte trecho de código

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = "~/Views/AcessoNegado.cshtml",
    ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData,
    TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData,
};
```

Porém, quando esta situação ocorre, a minha página `AcessoNegado.cshtml` não está sendo carregada. Ela está sendo renderizada dentro da modal.

Tentei retornar uma *ViewBag* indicando que ocorreu falha na autenticação para não exibir a modal, mas ele sempre vem `null`.

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para solucionar este problema da melhor forma possível.

Comment: Tem um problema na sua formulação. Dependendo do resultado do Ajax, a tela requer uma transferência de estados. Ou seja, seu Ajax não deve retornar um `ViewResult`. Você precisa decidir se a lógica tem que transferir o estado da tela ou não. Se não for, o correto é exibir uma mensagem em JS explicando a falta do acesso.

Comment: Na verdade, o redirecionamento para uma nova página é uma definição do escopo da aplicação... Não sendo ViewResult, tem alguma ideia do que posso retornar? Ou é necessário realizar uma mudança na forma em que o controlador está sendo chamado e consequentemente a Modal?

Comment: Para funções que não retornam partialView e não são abertas em modal, o redirect funciona corretamente.

Comment: Dentro do que eu entendi, o resultado da modal deve ser um JSON contendo algum código com regra de negócio. Se não houver permissão, o JS deve transferir a tela para a tela de não autorizado.

Comment: Eu estava tentando retornar alguma indicação após a chamada Ajax para que o evento "load" da modal não fosse executado, evitando que a página "sem permissão" fosse aberta dentro da modal

Comment: Estava pensando em uma forma de, quando ocorrer o redirect pelo controller, o evento que abre a modal não fosse executado...

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se você já resolveu isso, mas uma maneira genérica de resolver esta questão é utilizando os Headers da requisição.

No Controller da sua partialView você faz as suas validações e adiciona a URL da página de erro em alguma tag do Header:

```
HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Denied", "url/paginadeerro");
```

E pode usar o ajaxComplete do jQuery, o ajaxComplete é uma função aonde é possível fazer um bind de todos os Ajax executados na página, assim você pode validar se o Header existe, e fazer o redirect para a página de erro:

```
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var h = xhr.getResponseHeader("Denied");
    if (h !== undefined && h !== null) {
        alert("Acesso negado!");
        window.location.href = h ;
    }
});
```